# C#でList<構造体>とした時、ヒープメモリなのかスタックメモリなのか？

Tags: c#, unity3d, .net, メモリ管理

UnityのC#でコードを組んでいて疑問に思ったことなのですが、
構造体はスタック領域を使うと書いてあるのですが、
Listに関しては記述がなく、値型でない限りは参照型になるので
ヒープ領域を使うと思っています。

#### 質問

1. List<構造体>とした時は、どちらにメモリが確保されるのでしょうか？
2. また、スタックに確保されたか？ヒープに確保されたか？を知る方法はないでしょうか？

#### 経緯

UnityのC#ではヒープ領域がガベージコレクションで解放されないため、
１度ヒープ領域が更新されるとアプリを落とすまでヒープを確保し続け
アプリの確保メモリが非常に大きくなるため、スタックに移行できるものが
あればスタックに移行したいと思い、このような質問をしました。

#### 環境

- Unity 5.0.1f1
- .NET 2.0
- C# 4.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 構造体はスタック領域を使う

は正確ではありません。

構造体は置かれた場所をそのまま使うと言えばいいでしょうか。ローカル変数として構造体を宣言した場合、ローカル変数はスタックを使うため構造体はスタックを使うと言えます。しかし、クラスメンバーとした場合、そのクラス内に存在するだけで、クラスがどこに配置されたかに依存します。（そしてクラスはヒープを使うため構造体もヒープ上に存在することになります。）

Comment: 構造体のArrayを持った場合は、スタックに積まれるのでしょうか？
クラスは使っておらず、個数が分かっていれば固定長配列にできると思うので、こちらはスタックになるのではと思います。

Comment: C#では値型（構造体、数値、enumなど）以外は全て参照型であり、参照型は全てヒープを使用します。配列ももちろん参照型でヒープです。

Answer (score 4):

`List<T>`を含めて多くのコレクション型はデータの格納に配列を利用していますが、C#の配列は[特に明示](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx)しない限りローカル変数であってもヒープに配置されます。

Comment: 特に明示しない限りの部分勉強になりました、
やはりヒープ領域なんですね。
ヒープ領域を増やさない方法を模索中でして引き続き試行錯誤したく思います。

Answer (score 3):

> UnityのC#ではヒープ領域がガベージコレクションで解放されないため、
>   １度ヒープ領域が更新されるとアプリを落とすまでヒープを確保し続け
>   アプリの確保メモリが非常に大きくなるため、スタックに移行できるものが
>   あればスタックに移行したいと思い、このような質問をしました。

とのことですが、これは正しくないと思います。
構造体(より正確には値型）のListを生成した場合、他の方が回答なさっているように、
ヒープ領域（マネージヒープ）にその実体は存在することになります｡
ただ、このマネージヒープ領域はガーベージコレクタの管理対象であり､参照が完全に無くなったListはどこかのタイミングで、ガーベジコレクトされます。

ただし、値型の内部にネイティブリソースへの参照などを保持している場合は､
参照先のネイティブリソースは、その実体がアンマネージヒープに存在するので､
当然ガーベジコレクタの管理対象には成りませんので､適宜管理が必要になると思います。

また、アンマネージリソースの管理手法としてありがちな、ファイナライザでのリソースの開放は値型の場合､ファイナライザを含むことができないので、参照型の作成を考慮すべきかも知れません。

Answer (score 1):

`List`は、`class`とあるので、`new List<StructType>()`で生成されたオブジェクトはヒープに置かれるのでは？

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx